# How to get grouped items with limit numbers in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I create web applications using Ruby on Rails ver 5 and MySQL.
The application has two tables `categories` and `posts` , one of `categories` have multiple posts (`Category has_many :posts` and `Post belongs_to :category`). The table structure is like the following.

- Category Model

  - id: int
  - name: varchar
- Post Model

  - id: int
  - category_id: int
  - title: varchar

I have some questions.

1. Is it possible to get 30 posts grouped by categories without `group_by` query? But sending only one query.
2. What's a query for Ruby on Rails using ActiveRecord or ... Arel (with or without `group_by`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that for one query categorized:

```
Category.eager_load(:posts).map{|category| {category.name => category.posts}}.first(30)
```

Have fun

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood using `map` is sending N+1 queries. Thanks!